# NavbarAnimation.Maui With TabbedPage

Tags: .net, xamarin.forms, maui

I'm trying to use the package [NavbarAnimation2](https://github.com/RadekVyM/Navbar-Animation-2/tree/main), but it uses the shell to render the tabs. I'm trying to convert it to use only the TabbedPage, but I'm not succeeding. Has anyone tried to change it to use only TabbedPage?

I recreated the files, and I'm trying to implement using only the TabbedPage.